# XSLT - Retrieving SQLdata with PHP

Tags: php, sql, xslt

I'm having a surreal amount of trouble implementing XSLT that will have a simple effect on my current webpage text.

I have an XSLT that displays basic text and tables on a webpage. I want to have a **TextInput** and a **Button** that will add to my SQL database when used. However, I can't figure out how to even access the database from within XSLT or how to run PHP functions from XSLT to access the database. Moreover, I need to be able to read the input field and react to the clicking of the button.

Why can't I do this in XSLT? I've scoured the manuals and internet but could really use some help.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, XSLT cannot access a database, nor call PHP functions directly. You could stretch it to fetch URLs that cause db access to happen, but that's not what it's designed for.

Moreover, XSLT isn't meant to run in response to browser events (button clicks). It's usually run on the server to create the page (HTML and javascript, perhaps), and then XSLT does not come into the picture again until the next page transition.

What you probably want to do is have event handlers (onchange, onclick) assigned to your text input and button, and/or a form action, which invoke (possibly asynchronously) URLs that run PHP scripts on your server that add to your SQL tables. The sole role of XSLT in this scenario is to produce the initial HTML/Javascript page from whatever XML data you are feeding it.

The above is pretty compressed: you could write pages, expanding the various parts of it. If you have questions about particular parts of it, let me know what interests you.